# Incorrect review 'counter'

Tags: support, review-page

**I've only been having this problem for the past few days**, but since it hasn't resolved itself I thought I'd post here to see if it's been reported.

Basically, my review counter seems to be out of whack. For example, I refer to the image below:

[image]

As you can see, it's showing nine items in the queue. However, when I go in to review the items, I see a tally of zero next to all the review queues. In some cases there are some items to review, but these do not add to the total shown in the counter (but this I understand as the queue may just be getting cleared).

However, I know there is an issue here because as I type this, the review counter is still showing 9 but upon going to review the items they all have a tally of zero (and I've tested this fact in multiple browsers on multiple Macs).

So, has this been reported? Is it only affecting Ask Different, or is it across the Stack Exchange network?

Comment: There probably is already a question about this either here or on meta.stackexchange.com. AFAIR the counter shows the number of entries overall, not the number of entries pending for you.

Comment: Thanks @patrix - I haven't noticed this previously until a few days ago, so I feel whatever is happening now is somehow _different_ to what was happening previously. Just to clarify, when I posted the above question I checked in three browsers on two separate Macs, and in all cases it showed 9 items to be reviewed, and in all cases clicking on the _Review_ link showed me no items in any of the queues, although the counter still showed 9 items. Then, when I _refreshed_ the site, it still showed me that there are 9 items in the queue, even though there aren't any.

Comment: The situation is the same for every user. It doesn't matter whether you refresh, posts pending reviews by other users will still get counted even after you've completed your review

Comment: Oh, I see what you're saying. Thanks for the clarification. :) I crossed over the 10K mark a few days back, so that's probably why it's more obvious to me. Makes sense now! Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The top bar counter isn't specific to your user, whilst the /review page counters are. This means…

- Reviewing a post in the queue that still requires 1+ other users review too, you won't see the review task any more on /review but it'll still increment the top bar counter.
- If you've reviewed a post outside of a queue, you won't be able to review it again.
- This doesn't apply to you, but also <5k reputation users see tag wiki suggested edits increment the top bar but won't be shown in /review.
- …and of course some [copious caching](http://shouldiblamecaching.com).

[status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

Comment: I have a suspicion if you skip a review, you also contribute another source of off by one.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info. It all makes much more sense to me now! :)