# Can we have notifications for review queues?

Tags: discussion, review-page

I am looking for a way to get notifications in real time as when I earn reputation or have something in my inbox but for review queues.

I have seen in other Meta SE questions that it was the case before but it doesn't seem to be the case now. When there's a new action to review, I need to click on the icon to check and eventually there will be a grey dot next to the category.

Is it possible to parameter something or make the review queues have live notifications that could be shown without clicking on the icon in some way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The review icon [may have a red dot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/302226/295232) under some circumstances, but on Ask Different we have many users helping out in the review queues (thanks a lot!) so that rarely happens.

You'd have to keep in mind that notifications (in general) are meant for *urgent* things; the review queues are *important* but generally do not contain items that need *immediate* attention; they certainly can wait for a few hours. There has never been a notification system, other than that you receive inbox notifications for suggested edits on your own posts.

Comment: This is an example where the OP is talking about what I call "notifications" : https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2991/incorrect-review-counter

Comment: Oh right, now I remember. IIRC, those were only suggested edits, and that counter has been removed more than five years ago ...